# Grails using postregSQL phonetic search

Tags: grails

I'm having problem with `like` in my queries so I want to know if you could help me find a workaround. Is there any kind of phonetic search that can be used?

Comment: what exactly is your problem?

Comment: umlauts are the problem

Answer (score 0):

What's your Postgres version?

There was a bug in PostgreSQL prior to version 9, where Umlauts or other special chars where not treated correctly in `LIKE` statements.

Apparently this is fixed in newer versions. I didn't have problems with it, and I'm pretty sure my application produces search queries with umlauts.

If you can't update or still have a problem with Umlauts, you might try this workaround:

[Link](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4135DE5B.2000805@webde-ag.de)

> One solution:
>
> select replace( replace( replace( replace( 'Test ä ö ü ß', 'ä','ae'),
>   'ö','oe' ), 'ü','ue'), 'ß','ss' );
>
> ```
>   replace
> ```
>
> ------------------   Test ae oe ue ss
>
> If you also have upcase-characters, you have to extend the statement.

Or read more about localization and its problems here:

[PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/charset.html)